# Using VB6 dll in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb6

I am using vb6 dll in c#.net. It is working properly but when I host it on iis then it shows an error

```
S**ystem.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Unable to show modal form within this context**
```

I am using VB6 dll in following way
first register it, then add reference in my project and use it

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: Error indicates that your VB6 code is trying to put up a modal dialog - so you should try to check VB6 code and eliminate that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't show dialogs or message boxes on a web server.  If that error wasn't checked, somebody would have to break into the server room to click the OK button.

Answer (score 1):

There is the compiler option "unatteded execution" in vb6 forcing it to suppress message boxes and error messages. Compile it that way and vb6 writes such output to the event log.